# Short story where the Bethlehem Star proves to be a supernova, and an expedition visits its remains

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of a short story where astronomers find the exact position where the Star of Bethlehem (a supernova in that story) was and an expedition is sent to it. If I remember correctly, the fact that it was the star of Bethlehem is only revealed to the reader very late in the story (of course, the expedition knew it from the beginning, this is why they went there in the first place).

Comment: In the Clarke story, they did not know the precise date before the expedition.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was almost certainly turned into [an episode of the 1980s Twilight Zone show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_(The_Twilight_Zone)).

From the Wikipedia entry:

> This episode is based on a short story, "The Star" by Arthur C. Clarke, which was first published in Infinity Science Fiction (November, 1955). However, while Clarke's story ended with the priest in despair after the revelation that the alien civilization had perished in order to light "the Christmas star," the TV episode included the addition of an epitaph by the aliens, revealing their optimism about their place in the universe.

So the [correct answer is this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_(Clarke_short_story)).

Comment: I've seen the episode and read the story. Both excellent.

Answer (score 21):

I remember reading this story. [The Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_(Clarke_short_story)) by Arthur C Clarke fits the plot, is in a collection I would be likely to have read, and contains a quote I remember. So it's the one I remember reading; perhaps it's also the one you remember reading. You can [read it online](https://web.archive.org/web/20080718084442/http://lucis.net/stuff/clarke/star_clarke.html) now.