# Short story in which a spaceship explosion becomes the star over Bethlehem

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, spaceship

A friend once wrote a short story that I **think** he **may** have plagiarized.  I don't remember all the details, but the gist was that a crewman on a spaceship killed his crew mates and blew up the ship, and the explosion was visible from earth;  in fact, it became the legendary star which the wise men followed to Bethlehem.  Some of the particulars may have been changed a bit, but the most important points were the spaceship exploding and the wise men seeing it.

Note:  It is entirely possible that my friend did invent the story himself.  If this is the case, there is no correct answer to this question.

Note 2:  It should be obvious that this question is not a duplicate of the one linked [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/short-story-where-the-bethlehem-star-proves-to-be-a-supernova-and-an-expedition) (Short story where the Bethlehem Star proves to be a Supernova and an expedition visits its remains), as the plot is quite different.  The star is not a star, it is a spaceship explosion.  The story ends with the explosion being seen from earth, and no expedition is sent to investigate it.

Comment: Is your mate Chris deBurg? http://youtu.be/GmZg7tvGN9o

Comment: A ship exploding would not be bright enough or last long enough to compare to a bright star for days.

Comment: Depends on the ship. The Tardis blowing up acted as a replacement sun for 2000 years.

Comment: @cde - I'm not asking if the story is plausible.  I'm asking what the name of the story is.  If you have issues with the likelihood of the plot, you can write a letter to the author once he or she is identified.

Comment: I could totally imagine the wise men standing there and going "Did you see that? It just exploded" "Yeah, I know, but I don't have the time to go back and change my boxers." "wait what?"

Comment: There was a gaga cartoon in one of the many HEAVY METAL magazine imitators of the early 80s that was exactly like this: Two incompetent aliens destroy their spaceship through poor service and bad management and the wreckage burns, forming the Star of Bethlehem... Cant recall the source though.

Comment: Since this is unanswerable (OP was mistaken in his assumption that the story was plagiarised), I've elected to delete it at the OPs request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short story where the Bethlehem Star proves to be a supernova, and an expedition visits its remains](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27470/short-story-where-the-bethlehem-star-proves-to-be-a-supernova-and-an-expedition)

Comment: @randal'thor - That doesn't match the story I am asking about.  In my story, the star isn't a star at all, it is an exploding spaceship.

Comment: @WadCheber OK, sorry. VTC balefired.

Answer (score 19):

I'd say the story was written by A. C. Clarke, and the title is: [The Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_%28Clarke_short_story%29)

Comment: I'm not sure that's it, but it is very interesting.  Thank you.

Comment: It's not a ship in that story.

Comment: @DJClayworth, ah, you're right, an entire alien civilization's home planet was destroyed when their sun went nova. My mistake.

Answer (score 7):

You might be having trouble finding the story because it might not be a *short story* — at least not totally.  Parts of the idea might come from a *song* :

**Chris De Burgh — "A Spaceman Came Travelling" (1975)**

> A spaceman came travelling on his ship from afar,
>
> 'Twas light years of time since his mission did start,
>
> **And over a village he halted his craft,**
>
> **And it hung in the sky like a star, just like a star...**
>
> He followed a light and came down to a shed,
>
> Where a mother and child were lying there on a bed...

In short, I think your friend has probably merged Arthur C. Clarke's ["The Star"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_%28Clarke_short_story%29), a 1956 short story about an ancient supernova (revisited in 1985 in *[The Twilight Zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Star_(The_Twilight_Zone))* ), with De Burgh's song and then maybe added in some dramatic bits about psychotic crew members, producing something that could very well be unique.

Comment: I'll have to subtly ask my friend if he's ever heard the song.

Comment: Whether I accept this answer shall depend upon what my friend says.  This is getting complicated.  :)

Comment: @WadCheber : That's fair.  Either way, I'm very curious to see what your friend says!

Comment: @WadCheber : Even if your friend never read "The Star", he / she may have watched the *The Twilight Zone* episode based on it...

Comment: @Wad: Why will you "have to"? Why do you care?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Because I want to know the answer to the question.